# Switch Statement within a switch statement

Tags: java, input, switch-statement

I am trying to create a program to play rock paper scissors with the computer using switch statements. The problem I am having is that the program is telling me the second switch statement (switch (user){ ) is unreachable. Any tips would help.

UPDATE: Unreachable problem fixed! Problem is that switch statement is not reading individual computer choice and outputting all.

```
Example Output:
Please enter an integer between 0 and 2 to play ( 0 = Rock 1 = Paper 2 = Scissors): 2
The computer chose Rock!
You chose Scissors! You loose!
The computer chose Paper!
You chose Scissors! You win!
The computer chose Scissors!
You chose Scissors! It's a draw
```

Program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RockPaperScissors
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int comp = (int)Math.random()*3;
      System.out.print("Please enter an integer between 0 and 2 to play ( 0 = Rock 1 = Paper 2 = Scissors): ");
      int user = input.nextInt();

      while(user < 0) {
         System.out.print("Invalid integer, please type in a new number above zero and less than two: ");
         user = input.nextInt();
         }

      switch (comp){
         case 0: System.out.println("The computer chose Rock!"); break;
         switch (user){
            case 0: System.out.println("You chose Rock! It's a draw!"); break;
            case 1: System.out.println("You chose Paper! You win!"); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("You chose Scissors! You loose!"); break;
            }
         case 1: System.out.println("The computer chose Paper!"); break;
         switch (user){
            case 0: System.out.println("You chose Rock! You loose!"); break;
            case 1: System.out.println("You chose Paper! It's a draw!"); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("You chose Scissors! You win!"); break;
            }
         case 2: System.out.println("The computer chose Scissors!"); break;
         switch (user){
            case 0: System.out.println("You chose Rock! You win!"); break;
            case 1: System.out.println("You chose Paper! You loose!"); break;
            case 2: System.out.println("You chose Scissors! It's a draw"); break;
            }
         }

}
}
```

Comment: Look at where your `break` statements are. Code after a break unreachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `break` after before `switch (user){`, so your statement is `unreachable`.

Try this:

```
switch (comp){
     case 0: System.out.println("The computer chose Rock!"); 
     switch (user){
        case 0: System.out.println("You chose Rock! It's a draw!"); break;
        case 1: System.out.println("You chose Paper! You win!"); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("You chose Scissors! You loose!"); break;
        }
     break;
     case 1: System.out.println("The computer chose Paper!"); 
     switch (user){
        case 0: System.out.println("You chose Rock! You loose!"); break;
        case 1: System.out.println("You chose Paper! It's a draw!"); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("You chose Scissors! You win!"); break;
        }
     break;
     case 2: System.out.println("The computer chose Scissors!");
     switch (user){
        case 0: System.out.println("You chose Rock! You win!"); break;
        case 1: System.out.println("You chose Paper! You loose!"); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("You chose Scissors! It's a draw"); break;
        }
     break;
     }
```

Comment: The remover of the breaks indeed fixed the unreachable problem and compiles but now outputting each case without determining which number computer chose.
Example:
Please enter an integer between 0 and 2 to play ( 0 = Rock 1 = Paper 2 = Scissors): 2
The computer chose Rock!
You chose Scissors! You loose!
The computer chose Paper!
You chose Scissors! You win!
The computer chose Scissors!
You chose Scissors! It's a draw

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just move the break statement after the inner switch.

When compiler sees break

```
        case 0:
            System.out.println("The computer chose Rock!");
            switch (user) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("You chose Rock! It's a draw!");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("You chose Paper! You win!");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("You chose Scissors! You loose!");
                    break;
            }
```

> ```
>          break;
> ```

similarly for rest of the cases. The statements after the break or return will not be executed. 
So the compiler reports that these are unreachable statements.

Answer (score 0):

@user3358795: You are using break statement before inner switch statement this is the reason inner switch is going unreachable.

try the following code:

```
switch (comp){
     case 0: System.out.println("The computer chose Rock!"); 
     switch (user){
        case 0: System.out.println("You chose Rock! It's a draw!"); break;
        case 1: System.out.println("You chose Paper! You win!"); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("You chose Scissors! You loose!"); break;
        }
     break;
     case 1: System.out.println("The computer chose Paper!"); 
     switch (user){
        case 0: System.out.println("You chose Rock! You loose!"); break;
        case 1: System.out.println("You chose Paper! It's a draw!"); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("You chose Scissors! You win!"); break;
        }
     break;
     case 2: System.out.println("The computer chose Scissors!");
     switch (user){
        case 0: System.out.println("You chose Rock! You win!"); break;
        case 1: System.out.println("You chose Paper! You loose!"); break;
        case 2: System.out.println("You chose Scissors! It's a draw"); break;
        }
     break;
     }
```